# value selected afer dropdownlist selected changed event called

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dropdownlist I want to select a value SELECT File after click on selected change index
call.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="pdfdropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="pdfdropdown_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select file</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="open">download excel</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="download">dowload pdf</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>


protected void pdfdropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
    pdfdropdown.SelectedValue = "-1";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name + ".pdf");
    //......funtions script
}
```

But I was wonder when i download the file. Selected value is not selected.(After downloading) how can i change a value of dropdown

Comment: Remove this `pdfdropdown.SelectedValue = "-1";` in selected_indexchange, it will work!

Comment: I think it won't work.  because download files use response stream to write file not the html content.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
pdfdropdown.Items.FindByValue("-1").Selected = true;
```

Comment: what is happening ? which value is getting selected if you are doing this?